# SQL update a table with a foreign key

Tags: sql

I have a categories table, which one of the fields serves as the foreign key for a sub-categories table.  One field that serves as part of the primary key for each table is the language id.  I need to update these in both tables.  Basically, wherever the language id = x in both tables, I need to set it to y.

When I try to do an update on either table, I get a 'The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint..' which refers to the foreign key constraint.

How can I update the language field on both of these tables?

Comment: Looks like your `y` does not exist in the referenced (foreign key) table. You need to add it first.

Comment: SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? And you have circular FK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are doing a 1 time fix, drop the constraint, UPDATE and then add the constraint back.

If you need to do this as part of the application, insert one category row, update the sub-categories row, and then delete original category row.

Answer (score 7):

Use this, no need to remove and add as well.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
    NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FoerignKey_Name

--update query here

ALTER TABLE Table_Name
    CHECK CONSTRAINT FoerignKey_Name
```

For more info MSDN link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-foreign-key-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 5):

You need to drop the constraints, update the values, and then re-add the constraints.

Comment: OP doesn't say if this is one time or part of the business logic.  This method is good for one time conversions, but not application based transactions.

Answer (score 4):

You could change your constraint to [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: +1 which is what I thought too... unless the DB engine does not support this

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to disable the constraints first, do the update and then enable the constraints again.

Check out this [article](http://odetocode.com/Articles/79.aspx) by OdeToCode discussing this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm always leery about disabling constraints, and you *really* don't want to do that if this is a common operation.

An admittedly ugly alternative is to:
 - Create a row in the parent table, based on the row to be updated but containing the new foreign key value
 - Update all child rows where the foreign key contains the old value with the new value.
 - Delete the now-unused parent key row

This is awkward for any number of obvious reasons, and may not be suitable to your implementation, but it maintains referential integrity within the database.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the constraint, UPDATE and then ADD the constraint back

> `ALTER TABLE X DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_fkey;`
>
> `UPDATE TABLE Y SET col1='', id=2 WHERE id=3;`
>
> `ALTER TABLE X ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_fkey FOREIGN KEY (X_id) REFERENCES Y(id);`

postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.5

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new row, with the updated data and delete the old rows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).